# How i can call the function of other component?

Tags: reactjs

I have two classes:

```
class A extends Component {
   callMyFunction = () => {

   }
}

class B extends Component {
   callOtherFunction = () => {
      A.callMyFunction(); // It doesnt works
   }
}
```

How to call this from class B in otherFunction?

Comment: How do A and B interact with each other? Does A render B? What you're asking is much too broad.

Comment: such specifics should not matter, I'm just asking how to call a function of А class in B class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the specifics do matter. Because there would be different ways of doing this depending on how the two components interact with each other.

If class A is not a child component of class B (meaning you are not rendering class A inside of class B), then you can just import `callMyFunction` in the class B file.

```
import { callMyFunction } from '[relativePathToClassA]'
```

Then you can call callMyFunction pretty much wherever inside of class B.

```
class B extends Component {
   callOtherFunction = () => {
      callMyFunction()
   }
}
```

I do not usually work with class components so there may be some nuance there that I am leaving it but this is the general idea.

I will leave my answer there because I believe this should give you what you want based on the limited information provided in your question. If not, feel free to elaborate by responding to @codemonkey's comment and I can explain more as well.